# Can we add shared element transitions from a fragment recyclerview to bottom sheet dialog in android?

Tags: android, shared-element-transition, android-bottomsheetdialog

I want to display a bottom sheet with shared element transitions when I click on the adapter item icon, but my code is not working.
I am using this tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@isa.rufullazada/shared-element-transition-with-recyclerview-android-kotlin-5280b36813eb) except that I am passing the transitions to a bottom sheet.

Can someone help?